# Android: Drawable does not show correctly

Tags: android, expandablelistview

In my app  i have an expandable list view that i want to set `groupIndicator` for it, i add an image for it but image have an elongation, i don't have any idea.
How can i fix it?

these are my code and the picture of expandable list view:

```
<ExpandableListView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/expandableListView"
            android:groupIndicator="@drawable/group_indicator"/>
```

group_indicator.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/browser" android:state_empty="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/minus1" android:state_expanded="true"></item>
</selector>
```

[image]

Comment: see the xml attributes here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

Comment: @pskink: ican't open this page, it's not load for me

Comment: its ExpandableListView documentation

Answer (score 0):

Well you should actually post list_item.xml or whatever you called it, design for item.. where you have some ImageView and Checkbox..

Your ImageView, should have scaleType="center" or something like that.. that should help you.. or make your layout_width for that ImageView wrap_content instead of some fixed size :) because that seems to be wrong too.

Comment: i set scalType for what?